# Axios not sending XSRF token with headers

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I am integrating a Vue JS (Quasar framework) based SPA with API. The API is built in Laravel and is using sanctum for CSRF.

When I send a request to the sanctum endpoint `https://someweburl.com/sanctum/csrf-cookie` it sends the XSRF-TOKEN as cookie correctly. But when I am sending the the POST request, the X-XSRF-TOKEN is not attaching itself with the header. And I am getting a 'token mismatch' error.

The front-end is on my localhost:8080 while the API is live on a url. I do not have direct access to the Laravel project but only the API.

Following is my axios configuration

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

const apiBaseUrl = "https://someweburl.com";
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: apiBaseUrl });

api.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Vue.prototype.$api = api;
Vue.prototype.$apiBaseURL = apiBaseUrl;


export { axios, api, apiBaseUrl }
```

Following is the request format that I am trying to achieve i.e A POST request after getting the CSRF

```
export const fetchAllEvents = async function (context, payload) {
    this._vm.$api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        this._vm.$api.post('/api/website/event/all').then(response => {
            context.commit('setAllEvents', response.data.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

When I check use Postman to make the POST request with X-XSRF-TOKEN added as header, i am getting the correct response. Which means the API is working correctly. But there's some issue with axios.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` prior to `axios.create` and not on the instance default

Comment: Setting axios.defaults.withCredentials = true prior to axios.create didn't work. When I console.log the $api it shows the withCredentials set to true there. But the X-XSRF-TOKEN header is still not going the the requests.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is still having issue, i fixed it by adding this line to axios defaults

```
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true
```

Comment: This solved it! For anyone curious, this is why it works, the `withCredentials` seem to be or is going to be deprecated, we need to use `withXSRFToken` instead.
https://github.com/axios/axios/commit/cff996779b272a5e94c2b52f5503ccf668bc42dc

Answer (score 5):

Maybe that is because the **Axios** only sets the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header when the front and backend have the exact origin. You mentioned you are trying with your frontend app at your localhost and the API is on the web at another URL.

See the axios GitHub repository for more information: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/cd8989a987f994c79148bb0cacfca3379ca27414/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L179

Answer (score 0):

Check if cookie path in response header and front-end path are same. I had "XSRF-TOKEN" which had path "/iotconsoleapi-co" but my front-end url didnt contain such path. It gave error. So I changed the cookie-path to "/" and it worked like charm. The issue can arise if you are using Spring-boot since it automatically sets subdomain path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
  withCredentials: true,
  withXSRFToken: true,
```

and optional

```
  xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
```