# Laravel 10, Inertia, Vue3 in production - Error 419

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I developed an online shop using **Laravavel 10**, **Inertia** and **Vue3**.
Locally, everything works fine. There are no errors.
Problems arise when I deploy on the web server. One problem was solved thanks to valuable help from a user of this community.
The new problem concerns all **get, post, put** calls. 
Whenever I want to update or create a product or any other element such as categories, sizes, in short, everything, I get this problem in response:
[image]

Error 419 is usually an error related to csrf tokens in Laravel. Inertia uses Axios, so adding a token in requests should not be necessary.

And on the console, I have this second problem.

[image]

This is the code used to update a product to have an example.

**Vue component**

```
...
import {useForm} from '@inertiajs/vue3'
...


const updateForm = useForm({

    id: props.product.id,
    title: props.product.title,
    price: props.product.price,
    ....
});

function update() {

updateForm.put(`/admin/products/${props.product.id}`);

}
```

**Related Laravel Controller**

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            


        Product::where('id',$request->id)->update([
        'title' => $request->title
          ....
          ]);


        return redirect()->route('admin.products.edit', $id)->with('success','Product updated successfully');

}
```

You can do a product update via this [link](https://ecommerce.deniswebapp.ch/admin/products/BG4QesFgZ5b9XrRlkXugOq1jW2SP5ZyfV8IxSgXX9jMjpeUpqCBo7xruEdB9UI5kXHptAS755ywLOf8AArXRBIZ5Gp53SaNnGooMVHGEyvPYNkakzHp4ztNJWrFC7wYZ72FisxWYZKLMSkf6d8cZNrRaIR1bd7GHfYlr1ktIIvMYggtTQv89/edit) so you can see the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios not sending XSRF token with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002516/axios-not-sending-xsrf-token-with-headers)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have another kind of problem.

Comment: I'd say double-check. Testing your link, it's not passing the XSRF/CSRF token at all, nor does it have it in any sort of cookie

Comment: Have you tried doing an update from the link I posted?

Comment: I tried to put this line of code axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true in the axios configuration, but I have the same problem.

Comment: @Daniel `withCredentials ` needs to be used with `withXSRFToken` or at least according to their PR. If that still doesn't work then you need to actually provide a screenshot of the request and response headers - not just the HTTP status code. This is will help a lot more.

Comment: @Second2None 
For calls with Axios I am using a special composable in the project, in case I want to use custom code. I had inadvertently modified the code there. Where can I change the axios code for inertia? I am not using bootstrap.js and don't know where inertia goes to get axios. Could you please help me?

Comment: Check why your server isn't returning the `Set-Cookie` response header to se tthe XSRF cookie.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I am not familiar with servers and their configuration.  How can I check what you suggested I do?